# Comparing two lists with one list being user input always triggering flag

Tags: c#, operators

Im trying to create a game on windows form app for practice with really simple rules. A random jumble of letters is created and the user tries to type it out before time runs out. Im running into an issue when I compare the two lists. It is always triggering my GameOver bool, even when I make sure I typed the same.

```
public static void CheckGameOver()
    {
        if (code != Player.inputList)
        {
            GameOver = true;
        }
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeLeft.Stop();
        Player.inputList = userText.Text.ToList();
        Game.CheckGameOver();
        if (Game.GameOver == true)
        {
            this.Close();
            GameOverByInput gameOverByInput = new GameOverByInput();
            gameOverByInput.Show();
        }
        else if (Game.GameOver == false && Game.Level < 16)
        {
            this.Close();
            Game.WinRound();
            InbetweenLevels inbetweenLevels = new InbetweenLevels();
            inbetweenLevels.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

I think my understanding of `Player.inputList = userText.Text.ToList();` might be flawed and thats whats causing the issue. If any more info is needed I'll provide it.

Comment: A [mcve] (including how `code` is declared and assigned to) would be awesome.

Comment: @TheGeneral I think so? Sorry I'm still pretty new to programming. When I check whats in Player.inputList by printing it to a label box, it does show what the user typed.

Comment: When and where has code been asigned, which values have been passed onto it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing two lists, while **they both can have the same elements**, you are comparing **two separate references** in your code.

That means that **they are different** and thus, **your condition to set the GameOver flag to true is satisfied**.

You have many options to perform a comparison that suits better what you are looking for.

1. You can compare that **the lists have the same amount of members** and after that, iterate and **compare the elements of each list by index**, that means you compare the first element of the code list with the first element of Player.inputList and so on, if you iterate through all the elements and the condition is satisfied, then **the lists are holding the same information** and thus, **can be considered the same list**. (You can also use [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve the same behaviour)
2. Instead of using lists to hold the values, use **strings for both the code variable and player.inputList** and then, compare those two strings as when strings are compared (either through == or the .Equals method) the comparison will evaluate if each string hold the same information (the string reference type has been written to perform this comparison instead of evaluating if each string are pointing to the same reference), if you compare a string to another string and they contain the same text or characters, the **comparison will return true to show that the strings are equal**.

These are just the tip of the iceberg, you have many more ways to check for equality, I recommend you to seach dotnetperls and read every article it has, which might help you better understand why your comparison is not working as you expect it to.

Comment: will update with your insights, they are really nice, my wording for the strings type is not the best one

Comment: Thank you! I got it working with the first option. I'll look over that resource you told me about and try to make it work how I originally planed later, just for the challenge